How to make the Get.bottomsheet rotate to landscape mode, with the style of popping out from the right side?
I have handled the situations for landscape and portrait mode in the following way, but this method obviously does not take effect when the screen is rotated while the bottomsheet is open.
final isLandscape =
      MediaQuery.of(Get.context!).orientation == Orientation.landscape;

  if (isLandscape) {
    return showGeneralDialog(
      context: Get.context!,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierLabel:
          MaterialLocalizations.of(Get.context!).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
      barrierColor: Colors.black12,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation secondaryAnimation) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(1, 0),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(animation),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Material(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: bottomSheet,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  } else {
    return Get.bottomSheet(
      bottomSheet,
      isScrollControlled: isScrollControlled,
      settings: const RouteSettings(name: '/bottom_sheet'),
    );
  }

